# Error importing heatmap.js & heamap-leaflet.ja with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have this require-config file:
(there are more packages in the config ....)

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/static',
    waitSeconds: 10,
    packages: [
    {
        name: 'leaflet', 
        location: './bower_components/leaflet-dist',
        main: 'leaflet'
    },
    {
        name: 'heatmap', 
        location: './bower_components/heatmap.js-amd/src',
        main: 'heatmap'
    },
    {
        name: 'heatmapleaflet', 
        location: './bower_components/heatmap.js-amd/src',
        main: 'heatmap-leaflet'
    }
    ]
});
```

When I try to use heatmap or heatmap-leaflet, requireJS can't find the packages and show them as undefined.

```
require(['leaflet','heatmap','heatmapleaflet'],function(leaflet, heatmap, heatmapleaflet)
{
    console.log(leaflet); // Works
    console.log(heatmap); // undefined
    console.log(heatmapleaflet); //undefined
}
```

I tried different approaches and there is no result.

What is wrong?

Comment: Any updates on this?